# Excel Function to Sum the values in select cells

Tags: excel-formula

I'm looking for a function that will take the total week value, count the number of cells out to the right equal to the total week value, and provide a sum of those cells.

For example Cell A2 has the value of 3.  I want a function that will count out 3 cells to the right (B2,C2,D2) and sum the values of these 3 cells into cell E2.

Answer (score 2):

In cell E2, use the formula `=SUM(OFFSET($B$2,0,0,1,A2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It would look the value in the `Selection` and loop through it. For each value it would loop through the next cells in range and message the sum for that row. At the end it would message the sum of all the cells.

To customize, update code where message is popped.

> Use `Option Explicit` for preventing runtime errors due to undeclared
>   variables.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SumOfWeeks()
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim addr As String
    Dim rowSum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim totalSum As Integer

    For Each cell In Selection
        count = cell.Value
        rowSum = 0
        If IsNumeric(count) Then
            For i = 1 To count
               rowSum = rowSum + cell.Offset(0, i).Value
            Next i
            totalSum = totalSum + rowSum
            MsgBox "Sum of Row is: " & rowSum
        End If
    Next cell
    MsgBox "Total Sum is: " & totalSum
End Sub
```

Another alternative could be to create a string of range and find a `SUM` of the range. Treat this code as a point to start with and not a copy-paste solution.